# NSDistributedNotificationCenter listen for undocumented Apple Notifications

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications

I am developing a Mac OS X app for a client which has a feature where it displays the current default Text-to-Speech voice, and they want this to change when the user changes that through System Preferences. I have done a little experimenting and found that the system post a notification through the NSDistributedNotificationCenter called "com.apple.speech.DefaultVoiceChangedNotification". Are there any rules against this with app on the Mac App store. Does this count as using an undocumented API. The alternative would be to poll for changes, yuk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an API per se, just a notification you're listening for -
I suppose the biggest risk you're taking is that it'll break with even a minor OS update.

Unlikely that this will cause problems in the MAS approval process. No guarantees, though ;-)